# Why always error all rewrite using 'p' in first character?

Tags: .htaccess

I don't know what the problem with all my servers in Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 14.04 with LAMP 1-Click Applications.

when i try this .htaccess always return error 404  not found

```
  RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^privacy/$ page.php?name=privacy [L]
  RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

and other rule with 'p' in first character. but other name except 'p' in first character are work. There are example work code in my server :

```
 RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ index.php?cat=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/$ index.php?cat=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^find/tag/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

i tried all above in localhost and shared hostings is 100% work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be problem of enabling options `MultiViews` on your Ubuntu server.

Turn it off by placing this line as first line in your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/page` can be in URL but it will serve `/page.php`.

Comment: Finally works,, thanks. by the way that's line is enabling or disabling?

Comment: `Options -MultiViews` disables it and you need to disable it.

Comment: yeah i did, by the way how about in nginx? i have same problem with nginx in LEMP in Ubuntu server? [Here is my old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850247/some-nginx-rewrite-are-not-found)

Comment: Sorry I do not know Nginx that well.